# AngularJS: determine time elapsed, use to regularly update model and view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, timeout

### Context

I'm looking to create a webapp that looks at a set of data as a function of time elapsed since pageload. Think "how many calories have you burnt since opening this webpage".

I'm still trying to wrap my head around AngularJS services, factories, etc, and was wondering what the best way to create an auto-updating Timer that could be used to regularly (per second) manipulate and update ng-model.

### How I've (unsuccessfully) imagined it'd work:

I've got something like this at the moment:

```
app.factory('Timer', function($timeout) {
    var time = 0;

    var Timer = function() {
        this.time++;
        this.timeout = $timeout(this.Timer, 1000);
    }
});
```

And use as

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.someNgModelVarForTheView = Timer.time * $scope.data;
}, 1000);
```

But... well. In my mind that works beautifully. In reality screw all happens, and I'm kidding myself if I know the right way to do this...

### So I suppose, two questions:

- How do you calculate time since pageload, as a callable function?
- How do you recalculate the data model on a regular (per second) basis? Is $timeout a good method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to have your own service, you could do it like this:

```
.factory('MyTimer', function($interval){
    return function(delay){
        var initialMs= (new Date()).getTime();
        var result = {totalMilliseconds:0, counts:0};                
        $interval(function() {
            result.totalMilliseconds = (new Date()).getTime() - initialMs;
            result.counts++;
        }, delay);
        return result;
    };
 })
```

And you could use it like this:

```
.controller('testController', function($scope, MyTimer){    
    $scope.t = MyTimer(1000);
});
```

And in your html you could do this:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
   Total Ms: {{t.totalMilliseconds}}
   Counts: {{t.counts}}
</div>
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9wtwLxe5/1/)

Comment: That's exactly what I initially had in mind, thanks very much! Question though, are there any advantages to having this functionality as its own service, rather than just an unwrapped $interval function (as per my answer below?)

Comment: The most obvious advantage is that you can reuse it very easily anywhere that you want, even if it's a completely different project, another advantage is that you can test it independently, which is also good and also, look at the code that you needed to have in your controller without this "service wrapper" and after you have it... Performance-wise it's the same, but I think that your code will be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Eh, I ended up overcomplicating my thoughts. This did the trick:

```
var delay = 1000; // 1 sec
$scope.currentTime = 0;

$interval(function() {
  $scope.currentTime += delay;
  $scope.someData *= $scope.currentTime;
}, delay);
```

Comment: Bare in mind that the interval function doesn't get executed in the exact number of milliseconds that you have set in the "delay" parameter, therefore this approach that you are suggesting won't be completely accurate, it will be almost unnoticeable, but still I thought that you should let you know it.

Comment: I did notice it was always around 1002-1008 rather than 1000, but I'm not too fussed, and I feel like it'll be more effort to fix than is worth it considering the application :P

Comment: Of course! Also, please have a look at my answer, after all having that service could be quite useful, since it would make your code in the controller cleaner and easier to maintain. Thanks!